# Spring Apache Kafka send Message inside onSuccess of the first event

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

im working on java spring boot project , i want to send event to my topic A and verify if the message sent (onSuccess) then send my second message to topic B. here is my code :

```
public void sendMessageToTopicAandB(String message) {

       
        ListenableFuture<SendResult<String,String>> future = kafkaTemplate.send(toicA, message);

        future.addCallback(new KafkaSendCallback<String, String>() {

            @Override
            public void onFailure(KafkaProducerException ex) {
                logger.warn("Message could not be delivered. " + ex.getMessage());
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(SendResult<String, String> result) {
                
                // so here i want to trigger my kafkaTemplate.send(topicB, message);
            }
        });

}
```

can i call `kafkaTemplate.send(topicB, message);` inside `onSuccess()` of the first event, its a good idea ?
do you have any idea how i can make these calls correctly ?

Comment: It'll work. But you'll have another callback to implement

Comment: @OneCricketeer should i use my callback inside onSuccess() of the first one ?

Comment: `kafkaTemplate.send` returns a Future. If you want to gurantee a message is sent to topicB, then yes, it needs to be within the first onSuccess... Are you running into a specific error? Also want to point out that `new KafkaSendCallback` is its own object. It does not need to be within `sendMessageToTopicAandB` method. You could make a brand new class or variable for each callback like `class TopicACallback implements KafkaSendCallback<String, String> {}`